# Display a list of categories excluding the current one

Tags: categories, category

In a template for a category page, I'm trying to output a list of links through to all categories within a category group but exclude the category that the user is on.

Does that make sense? What I'm trying doesn't work, but I'm new to Craft and Twig!

Answer (score 5):

With a little help I got there:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('developmentType').id('not ' ~ category.id) %}
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
    <li><a href="{{ category.url }}" class="btn">{{ category }} Opportunities</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```